# javascript - text cutoff in the bottom/top while scrolling a table content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollbar

I am looking for a scrolling solution, I have a table with tr content, When I am scrolling the table the text is cutoff at the bottom and top.

Text cutoff in bottom
[image]

Text cutoff in top
[image]

I am looking for a perfect scroll, i.e., scroll record by record without any text cut off when scrolling the table content

Comment: If you add your code, I can help you implement this: https://css-tricks.com/practical-css-scroll-snapping/

Comment: code is available here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LaPLbE

Comment: i have tried to implement this but there is jump happening I mean scrolling is not smooth